Working with Maui .Net, I need create a Mac Catalyst App and open WhatsApp web in a web view
WhatsApp web never load the QR Code for scan.
In the output console I have the error:
**Cannot store WebCrypto master key, error -34018
**
All the features for enable javascript in the web view are ready and the user agent is seated.
I need to open WhatsApp web with the same behavior as a web browser.
